# Oracle SQL Issue with Joining tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been researching and trying to think of a way to do this, but am stuck.  I am using Oracle SQL and I have a table `PS_Z_TREND_NOW_TBL` with fields `DESCR254` and `STATUS`.  I want to find where

```
sec.IS_AW_GRP_ID is like... '%' || REPLACE(UPPER(trend.DESCR254), ' ', '%') || '%'
```

and I want to return `trend.DESCR254` with the number of instances in `PS_IS_AW_SECURITY` sec.  There are 11 total rows in `PS_Z_TREND_NOW_TBL` trend, so the results should look like the data at the bottom.  Does anyone see what is wrong with this query?  When I took out `COUNT(trend.DESCR254.*)` in the first row of the query I got 0 results when I know that I should get 11.

```
SELECT trend.DESCR254, COUNT(trend.DESCR254.*)
from PS_IS_AW_SECURITY sec, PS_Z_TREND_NOW_TBL trend
where sec.IS_AW_AUTH_NAME LIKE '%Manager%'
and sec.IS_AW_GRP_ID LIKE '%' || REPLACE(UPPER(trend.DESCR254), ' ', '%') || '%'
GROUP BY trend.DESCR254
```

Expected Result

```
test01  3
test02  1
test03  4
test04  7
..
..
test11  19
```

Comment: `sec.IS_AW_GRP_ID` rows all CAPS ?

Comment: @user3586248, why your using UPPER only on one side

Comment: What's the `COUNT(trend.DESCR254.*)` expression supposed to be doing?